# Show validation errors on webpage with spring-mvc?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

The following controller serves a simple html page showing all persons in a repository.

Problem: I'm using validation constraints on the get-query. And if the query was invalid (in my example: `lastname` parameter is missing), then spring automatically throws an exception as response to the browser.

But I'd still want to render the `persons.html` page, just showing the errors indead of the repository content.

Question: how could I achieve this? Because if the validation fails, the method below is not even accessed.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/persons")
public class PersonController {
    @GetMapping //note: GET, not POST
    public String persons(Model model, @Valid PersonForm form) {
        //on the persons.html page I want to show validation errors

        model.addAttribute("persons", dao.findAll());
        return "persons";
    }
}

public class PersonForm {
    private String firstname;

    @NotBlank
    private String lastname;
}
```

Sidenote: I'm using `thymeleaf` as templating engine. But the same question would apply to `jsp` or `jsf` engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `BindingResult` should solve this problem as @obecker pointed. I saw your remark, it works for `GetMapping` and `@PostMapping` as well.

Please check this out:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So45616063Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So45616063Application.class, args);
    }

    public static class PersonForm {
        private String firstname;
        @NotBlank
        private String lastname;

        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
        }

        public void setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return firstname + " " + lastname;
        }
    }

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public static class Home {

        @GetMapping
        public void get(@Valid PersonForm form, BindingResult bindingResult) {
            System.out.println(form);
            System.out.println(bindingResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Call:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:8080?firstname=f&lastname=l'
```

Will produce output:

```
f l
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors
```

Call:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:8080?firstname=f'
```

Will produce:

```
f null
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
```

Comment: Thanks for adding an example. Thereby I could also find my error when trying to use `BindingResult`: it is mandatory to add it right after the `@Valid` arguments to which it should be applied. I was not aware of this (probably this is also not clear enough from the docs).

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional `BindingResult bindingResult` parameter in the `persons` method. You can use this `bindingResult` to see whether there are validation errors.

Spring has a nice guide that shows how to do this.
See https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Comment: That's why I wrote explicit it is about a `GET` request. Your linked example with 'BindingResult` applies only to a `@PostMapping`!

Comment: Could you give a working example? If I add `BindingResult bindingResult` parameter to the `/persons` method above, it cannot be reached anymore and returns a 404.

Comment: @membersound I've provided you an example in my answer